How to transfer a 2d array to the desired position into the bigger grid?
I have a list of coordinates like this one:
[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4),……]
On the other hand I have the different type of data that is a list of  2d array (60*60).
With the cell of temperature how can I find the center position of this 2d array and translate, transfer or map to the coordinates list in bigger grid?
What is the best approach?

Hi, if it answered your question you might as well mark it as correct .
